# svn commands return error "symbol not found"

Tags: macos, svn, homebrew

After installing svn through homebrew on MacOS it quits every command with the following error:

```
dyld[25717]: Symbol not found: _apr_crypto_block_cleanup
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.14.1_4/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
```

Any idea how to fix that? I already reinstalled svn and updated brew.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution myself in reinstalling apr-util:

`brew reinstall apr-util`

Comment: It woks for me as well, thanks for the answer!